# How can I use Gmail to sync my calendar between Mac OS X and Android?

Tags: data-synchronization, ical, google-calendar, calendar, android

I've recently bought an HTC Desire and I'd like to sync my calendar from my MacBook Pro (Os X 10.6.6) with the calendar from the phone. I suppose it would be easiest to do it over Gmail, but I'm not sure how. I checked their site, and there is a simple tutorial how to do it if you want Gmail calendar events in iCal, but I need the opposite. How to do that?

Comment: You might find this question on the Android site about syncing desktop Outlook calendars and contacts with Google and Android helpful: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/sync-setup-question-android-outlook-2010-gmail-calendar-and-contacts

Answer (score 3):

The approach I took was to sync my phone with the gmail calendar and then sync iCal with google calendar. I don't sync directly between phone and mac.

I can add events on all three now and it will sync between all of them.

edit: I've been asked to post up a screengrab, but it honestly isn't needed. I've seen the guides on setting up CalDav but it's honestly not required, iCal has a really simply method to add an account which makes it extremely simple to do.

- Launch iCal
- Go to File -> Preferences
- Delete any accounts you think you might have set up incorrectly
- Add an account with the + button
- Leave the account type as Automatic
- Enter your google email address
- Enter your google password

That is IT! I have a personal and work calendar on google calendar and it brought both in.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You use Google calendar and you enter events to the Google calendar of iCal, or can you really sync events from the iCal to Google calendar and then have both? I hope you understand what I mean... Btw, I have three calendars in my iCal: home, work and holidays. I would like to have same thing on my phone and Gmail. I did the following: I copied all the events to Gmail calendar and then synced it to iCal. But then I had to delegate something and it looked really bad.. Can you explain exatly what you did and maybe put a screenshot of your iCal app?

Comment: Ivan, I have edited the answer with a few more pointers. Seriously, avoid the guides on the web, the current iCal software makes it very, very easy.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in thinking that the Google Calendar is the best way to go.

To sync between Google and your Mac you can set up the Google calendar as a CalDav, [Google have a comprehensive guide for this](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99355). If you already have everything in iCal you may have to export them into the Google calendar web interface, this is just a case of selecting "Export" in iCal and "Import" in Google calendar. FWIW After using this hybrid approach for a while I've actually started using the Google calendar web interface rather than iCal as it is a bit more flexible and gives more are to work with.

I'm not too hot on how to set stuff up on Android, but I thought everything was linked to your Google account anyway? (Google do have a [similar guide](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/topic.py?topic=21414) for Android, but I've not used it).

Comment: Once you've added your Google account on your Android device, it's dead-simple to sync the calendars.

Answer (score 0):

If you're syncing Google Calendar to a Mac, be sure to checkout [BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com/).

(It's accurately referred to as "iCal Pro" and will sync to Google Calendars, MobileMe, or generic WebDAV calendars.)

There's a demo on their website.